how to start workflow 2010 in SharePoint programmatically
I am running SharePoint Server 2019. I have created a workflow in SharePoint designer based on SharePoint 2010 Workflow. The environment does not have the SharePoint 2013 workflow.
I have tried using _vti_bin/workflow.asmx, see code below, but I am getting an error:
try {
            const requestDigest = await this.getFormDigest();

            const soapEnvelope = `
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soap:Body>
                    <StartWorkflow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/">
                        <item>https://domain/sites/site1/Lists/Cazes/171_.000</item>
                        <templateId>445F0EA1-3F50-4E6C-B849-6BB0446C0156</templateId>
                        <workflowParameters>
                            <root />
                        </workflowParameters>
                    </StartWorkflow>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>`;

            // Set up the URL for the SOAP request
            const soapUrl = "https://domain/sites/site1/_vti_bin/workflow.asmx";

            // Perform the fetch request
            const response = await fetch(soapUrl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
                    "SOAPAction": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/workflow/StartWorkflow",
                    "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
                },
                // body: soapEnvelope
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
            }

            const data = await response.text();
            console.log("Workflow triggered successfully:", data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        }



You can add error for your question?
